# Wrong example of not abelian homotopy category?

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory, homological-algebra

I was reading the book **Triangulated Categories** by Thorsten Holm, Peter Jørgensen, Raphaël Rouquier. I found in the book the example below.

[image]

The author wants prove that $K(\mathbf{Ab})$ is not  abelian and in order to do this he takes a zero-arrow $f$ and he claims that $f$ has not kernel. Is this example wrong? If I take the zero arrow $0\colon A\longrightarrow B$ in any additive category, then is it true that it has kernel given by the identity map of $A$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this example is wrong, since there is no contradiction when $r = 1$. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/407775/116766).

Comment: Yes, the zero arrow in any additive category has a kernel, by the usual definition of kernel. So it looks like the book is talking a load of nonsense. Unless perhaps they are using some unconventional definition of kernel (but why on earth should they do that?).

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Nope. The definition is the standard one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this example is just wrong.  You are correct that the identity map on $A$ is always a kernel of the zero map $A\to B$.  Their argument seems to assume that $r\mathbb{Z}$ cannot be all of $\mathbb{Z}$, but this is of course incorrect if $r=\pm 1$, which is exactly what happens for the identity map.