# Homotopy category is not Abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, triangulated-categories

I know this has been asked several times before. Some answers for this has been answered theoretical and some of the by counter example.The theoretical answers for this question are OK I want to give an easy couterexample why $K(A)$ since all the examples given before are more or less complicated  so I came to the following answer:

[(AB1) failure in $\mathcal{K(A)}$, without triangulated categories](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407775/ab1-failure-in-mathcalka-without-triangulated-categories)

But still don't understand why the counterexample at first answer works :/ First doubt there is why $fg=0$ and the second doubt is why it claims the last morphism there exist and should be homotopical to $g$ and Aldo why it claims the last morpshism cannnot be homotopical to $g$.  Sorry but I've been stuck on this for a while and really want to see a couterexample clearly for this

Comment: If you just want a counterexample, you can look at [one of my answers here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1284823/116766). Maybe this is one of the examples you saw before, though.

Comment: @TakumiMurayana Yes, I still see complicated to follow your argument there so I was looking for a simpler counterexample