# Defining $f$ and $g$ in $\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow[]{f} \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2 \mathbb{Z}} \xrightarrow[]{g} \mathbb{Z}$ such $fg=1_{\mathbb{Z}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, abelian-groups, abelian-categories

I already work a counterexample seems to work for answer my own question here:

[Homotopy category is not Abelian.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3388828/homotopy-category-is-not-abelian?noredirect=1#comment6972009_3388828)

But I need to know if in the following sequence of functions in the category of abelian groups

$$\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow[]{f} \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2 \mathbb{Z}} \xrightarrow[]{g} \mathbb{Z}$$

there is some way to define $f$ and $g$ such $gf=1_{\mathbb{Z}}$. My intuition says this is not posible but cannot justify why?

Comment: The domain of $g$ only contains two points. The range contains infinitely many points. How then can the image of $g$ be equal to the range of $g$ (which is also the range of $g\circ f$)? It can't.

Answer (score 7):

*Hint:* $g$ cannot be surjective.

Answer (score 1):

If such maps $f$ and $g$ exist then $f$ must be injective, but that is an absurd because $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is a finite group whereas $\mathbb{Z}$ is an infinite group.

Comment: if $f:\mathbb{Z} \to 2 \mathbb{Z}$ and $g: 2 \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ can $gf$ be $1_{\mathbb{Z}}$?  I think in this case $g$ can be surjective right?

Comment: I meant  as Abelian groups

Comment: Well the answer is yes but there is only way to the define f to get the identity on Z ??

Comment: Yes, in this case $g$ is surjective and $f$ is injective. You have a contradiction looking at either case.