# Homotopy category, map without kernel

Tags: proof-explanation, homology-cohomology

I was looking for some examples of an abelian category such that the associated homotopy category is (additive but) not abelian, and I have read an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407775/ab1-failure-in-mathcalka-without-triangulated-categories). Consider the category of cochain complexes of abelian groups and the map
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\cdots @>>> 0 & @>>> \mathbb{Z} @>>> 0  @>>> \cdots\\
@. @VVV @V{\pi}VV @VVV \\
\cdots @>>> 0 @>>> \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} @>>> 0 @>>> \cdots
\end{CD}$$
We would like to prove that in the homotopy category we don’t have a kernel. 
The author to the answer considers this map $g^\bullet$
$$\begin{CD}
\cdots @>>> 0 & @>>> \mathbb{Z} @>>> \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}  @>>> 0 @>>> \cdots\\
@. @VVV @V{id}VV @VVV \\
\cdots @>>> 0 @>>> \mathbb{Z} @>>> 0 @>>> \cdots
\end{CD}$$
Clearly the composition with the given map is homotopic to $0,$ hence there exists a (unique) map $\Phi^\bullet$ from
$$\begin{CD}
\cdots @>>> 0 & @>>> \mathbb{Z} @>>> \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}  @>>> 0 @>>> \cdots\\ 
\end{CD}$$
to the kernel $K^\bullet$ such that is $\imath^\bullet\circ \Phi^\bullet$ is homotopic to $g^\bullet$, where $\imath$ is the map that defines the kernel. He claims that no such map can exist, but it’s not clear to me why this is true. Can you give me an explanation?

Comment: The answer you linked to claims the kernel, if it existed, would have to be $0 \to 2\mathbb{Z} \to 0$. It's not obvious to me why that's true, but if it is, and if $\iota$ has to be the usual kernel (i.e. with the inclusion $2\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$), then it would be straightforward. Factoring $g$ as $\iota \circ \Phi$ would require $g^0 = \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ to factor through $2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You're right, at the end I have moved the attention on this fact, but I'm not sure on how to prove it. I know that the object in the homotopic category are the same objects of the complex category but I don't see how to prove that in the homotopic category, if kernel exists, would be the homotopy class of the kernel in the complex category. At least, it seems reasonable...